# Finding the area inside the region $1+\sin(\theta)$ but outside $r=1$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find the area inside the region $r=1+\sin(\theta)$ but outside $r=1$, this is my integral
$$A=\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \left[\left(1+\sin(\theta) \right)^{2}-1^{2} \right] d\theta$$

I know how to evaluate the integral but I don't know why I am getting a negative value... the first curve is the outer curve and $r=1$ is the inner curve, and that is why I am subtracting $(1)^{2}$ from $\left(1+\sin(\theta) \right)^2$ ... can someone kindly tell me if there is something I am missing here?

Comment: The two polar curves switch positions ($<$ to $>$) at those two end points, but you picked the wrong half. In the lower half, the first curve is the inner curve. The upper half gets you the region you want from the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the region satisfying $1<r\le1+\sin\theta$, which implies $\sin\theta>0$ and $0<\theta<\pi$. So your calculation should be of$$\frac12\int_0^{\pi}[(1+\sin\theta)^2-1]d\theta=\int_0^\pi[\sin\theta+\tfrac12\sin^2\theta]d\theta=2+\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!